# Generalized Binomial Model independent in the limit

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Start with a generalized binomial model

$$P(X_{n+1}=1\mid \mathcal{F}_n)=\theta_n+ n^{-1} d_n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$
$$P(X_{n+1}=1)=p_{n+1}=\theta_n + n^{-1}d_n \sum_{i=1}^n p_i$$

With $0\leq \theta_n+ d_n <1$.

Then if we impose $p_n=p_m=p$ for any $n,m$, the distribution is identical and exchangeable (given no information). Correct? This requires

$$p=\theta_n + d_np \iff p = \theta_n /(1-d_n),$$

but not necessarily that $d_n$ or $\theta_n$ converge as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Yet, for an exchangeable sequence, it will be an independent sequence in the limit. This leads me to believe $d_n \rightarrow 0$. But I don't know if this is justified or how to prove it if it is. Any ideas on how to interpret this kind of probability model if we require that each $X_n\in\{0,1\}$ is identically distributed?

Terminology question too: If $p_m=p_n$, would you call $X$ an exchangeable sequence *with respect to $\mathcal{F}_0=\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$*? It seems like it should be exchangeable only in some kind of ex ante sense.

Comment: I see no reason why $(X_n)$ should be [exchangeable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables) if $p_n=p$. Actually, $d_1=1$ already yields $(X_1,X_2)$ non identically distributed. Likewise $d_1=1$, $d_2=0$, yields $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ non exchangeable.

Comment: $d_n=1$ rules out $p_n=p$ though. I thought if $p_n=p$, then these should be identically distributed? Why won't a sequence be exchangeable if $p_n=p$. For a sequence of length 2, $\Pr((0,1))=(1-p)\theta_1$ and $\Pr((1,0))=p(1-\theta_1-d_1)$. Sub in $\theta_1=p(1-d_1)$ shows this is exchangeable.

Comment: No, $d_n=1$ does not rule out $p_n=p$, the only relation is $p=\theta_n+d_np$ (not the relation that you say equivalent although it is not when $d_n=1$...). I see that you silently added the condition that $\theta_n+d_n\lt1$, seemingly to exclude the possibility that $d_n=1$ since the counterexamples in my comment are based on this case. This is not how one should proceed. The cases I provided are just examples where one sees easily that things go wrong, but there are others. Even more importantly, *why do you think the results you state should hold?*

Comment: Okay, I was taking this from [Wu et al (2012)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167715211003841) where they require $d<1$. I will have to think about things for cases greater than two.

Comment: And thanks. A counterexample for d<1, $(\theta_0,\theta_1,\theta_2)=(1/4,3/16,1/8)$ and $(d_1,d_2) = (1/4,1/2)$. $\Pr((0,0,1))=\frac{3\times 13\times 1}{4\times 16\times 8} \neq \Pr((1,0,0))=\frac{1\times 9 \times 3}{4\times 16 \times 8}$. Now I'll have to figure out what structure would guarantee exchangeability.